# How to make click event trigger from a mousedown that was triggered manually?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I currently have a popped-up context menu. This popup gets closed when you click outside of it.

This is done with a div behind the popup that takes up the whole window, and listens for the `mousedown` event.

I need this mouse event to be sent to elements on the page behind the layer, so I call `trigger()` on those.

```js
function onLayerMouseDown(e) {
  layer.hide();
  $("#menu").hide();
  target = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft(), e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop());
  if (target != null)
    $(target).trigger(e);
```

This works well for the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, but the `click` event  which would come when the mouse presses and releases without leaving the element is never sent.

**How can I make it so the click event gets sent too?**

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yerpwtLq/28/) for an example with the layer. Click the text behind while the menu is open and see the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is easy to understand, but the solution will depend on your requirements. Once the `mousedown` event is sent, the first thing that the script does is to hide the `layer`. This means that it will no longer detect mouse events. This means that no `click` event is ever emitted, neither for the `layer` (the click event would need a `mouseup` inside the same element) nor for the `inside` (the `mousedown` event received is a copy and comes from `layer`). It is important to notice that the `click` event is managed by the browser. You cannot trigger a `click` by just sending a `mousedown` and then a `mouseup`. That also explains why `inside` receives a `mouseup` event, as this event only happens after `layer` has disappeared.

Regarding how to solve it, you might:

- Set the `layermousedown` function to handle the `click` event. With this design, it would mean that `mousedown` and `mouseup` are not captured.
- Change the design. The idea would be to set the `pointer-events` of `layer` to `none`:

```js
$("#inside").on("mousedown", (e) => {
    console.log("inside mousedown (triggered manually from the layer)");
});
$("#inside").on("click", (e) => {
    console.log("inside click (should happen right before mousup, if the mouse stayed inside the element");
});
$("#inside").on("mouseup", (e) => {
    console.log("inside mouseup (triggered automatically when releasing mouse button)");
});

$("#button").click(() => {
    createlayer();
  return false;
});


$(document).on('click', layermousedown);

$("#menu").click(() =>{return false});

function layermousedown(e) {
    $("#layer").hide();
    $("#menu").hide();
    $("#button").prop('disabled', false);
}

function createlayer() {
    $("#button").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#layer").show();
  $("#menu").show();
  console.log("added the invisible layer");
  console.log("_______________________");
}
createlayer();
```

```css
#layer {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  background-color: #000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: #ff5;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <span id="inside">click me please</span>
</div>
<div id="layer"></div>
<button id="button">
Add the layer again
</button>
<div id="menu">
<span>this is part of the menu</span>
</div>
```

The idea is to react to `document` events and intercept the `click` events in the elements that should not be responsive. That is why some callbacks return `false`.